# What is the probabilty that there are no 2 people in 12 people room with the same birthday month?

Tags: probability

What is the probabilty that there are no 2 people's in 12 people room with the same birthday month ?

I thought about $\frac{12!}{12^{12}}$,but , i think its wrong.
What do you think ?

Thanks.

Comment: i think it's correct. $P($ all people have different month of birth $) =$$\frac{12!}{12^{12}}$

Comment: It's correct, if you make the simplifying assumption that each month has an equal probability.

Comment: This was asked a few days ago.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1713324/the-probability-that-no-person-has-the-same-birthday-month?rq=1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475378/what-is-the-probability-that-nobody-is-born-in-the-same-month?rq=1